# Why is my Data frame empty after assigning values through a for loop?

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-analysis

I am trying to create a dataframe with the attributes I need from a json data object through for loop. But when I try to print the dataframe contents its showing empty even the loop ran successfully.

What I find weird is when I try to print

`table['h_timezone'].head()`

output is :

```
PST
PST
CST
```

But when I try to print table's content. it says empty data frame or 0 rows and 2 columns.

Btw, my file has 10,000 json objects/transactions and I am following the assignments process for 40 columns in the same for loop below.

Can anybody please help me with this issue? What am I exactly doing wrong in the code? Also, is there any efficient process to do the job?

```
import pandas as pd

import json 

data = pd.read_json(open('sample.json'), lines=True)

columns = ['h_timezone','h_apptimestamp']

table= pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)

for i in range(0,len(data)):

    table['h_timezone'].loc[i] = data.loc[i]['header']['timeZone']

    table['h_apptimestamp'].loc[i]=data.loc[i]['header']['applicationTimestamp']

table.count()
table.head()
```

expected output

```
h_timezone   h_apptimestamp
PST          09-09-2018 01:20:20
CST          10-09-2018 01:30:30
```

my output is coming as below:

```
table.count()
h_timezone      0
h_apptimestamp  0 

table.head()
h_timezone  h_apptimestamp
```

Comment: I think if you do table['h_timezone'].loc[i], you are actually setting the values in your for loop to a copy of the data. You can put 'h_timezone' inside your loc[] as follows:
`table.loc[i, 'h_timezone'] = data.loc[i]['header']['timeZone']`

Comment: @linamnt Thanks for the correction! It worked. Thanks for the explanation too. I understand the process now.